# Google Assistant prefers web browser over an installed app

Tags: android, google-assistant

When using **Google Assistant plugin for Android Studio** to test Assistant integration with an Android app it seems like it fails to recognise and direct BIIs to an installed app when the app name "sounds" like a web page (e.g. facebook.com, ynet.co.il, etc.) and always prefer to open a browser instead.

When another app name is used in the plugin everything works as expected.

[image]

Why is that and is there a way to override it without renaming the app? Also, is that a plugin behavior or something that should be expected also in production?

Appreciate your assistance.